# Missing "Macro Names'" button in Access "Macro Creation" interface

Tags: ms-access, ribbon

I'm in a ludicrous situation : I can no longer find a standard ribbon button that is explained here [Run an Access macro by using a keyboard shortcut](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/run-an-access-macro-by-using-a-keyboard-shortcut-0d267570-d3da-46eb-9bfb-a3c81af676be) : In "Macro design", the "Show/Hide" group should show a "Macro Names" button to switch the Macro editor in column mode. This button is not there.

I just want to create an "AutoKeys" macro, but I can't access to the "Macro Name" where I have to set the key...

This button is also not present at all in the "Customize Ribbon": all that is disponible in this group is "Action Catalog" and "Show All Actions".

This is not relevant to my problem, but I say it: the "Options/Trust Center/Macro Setting" is set to "Enable all macros". My Access version is 2210 build 15726.20174, installed in 32bits mode on a 64bits Windows.

I only use Macros to assign shortcuts key, I'm shure that I allready used this button in the past. All I can suspect is a problem in a really recent release. I'm about to use "SaveAsText" and "LoadFromText" hidden VBA functions.

Answer (score 0):

In fact I did use the hidden functions: I added a "MacroName="^D"" entry to the texte file and reloaded it: It worked fine and showed me that I really never use the Macros editor: it was all about defining a "Sub Macro", the "Macro Name" mode was not mandatory to what I wanted to do... Sorry. It remains that a Ribbon Button seems to have recently dissapeared.